# Blender Bending the elbow the right way on character

Tags: blender

I started learning character rigging in blender, and when I add a mesh to the armature, the arms on the mesh look twisted. I've tried changing the rotation on the arm with the pole angle in the bone constraints, and it works but it also changes which way the elbow bends. What other way could I rectify this, so that the elbow bends the right way but the mesh doesn't look twisted.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Blender and belongs on [blender.se].

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this I always find it easiest to enable weight painting. This lets you select each bone, and see which vertices in the mesh they deform, and by how much. Try doing this, and looking around your elbow. You can paint the weights onto the mesh or remove them if you want, until you have each bone affecting the parts you want it too.

Note that *every* vertex must have all of it's weights combine to 100%, otherwise they will drag behind the character when you move it.